# Проблема в SQlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite

не получается получить значение 0/1 с ячейки sms
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def get_sms(self,user_id):
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `user_id` = ?, `sms` FROM `users`",(user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
```

#output [(1, 0)]
Не понимаю откуда берется 1

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: вы же вроде сами в селекте запрашиваете два значения

Comment: `Select sms From users Where user_id =?` вернет кортеж `(sms,)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему если что, действительно не верно запросил значение

Comment: Это комментарий, а не решение вашей конкретной проблемы